# Estos 2 scripts juntos me generan un error

Tags: javascript, script, javascript-objeto

las 2 primeras lineas que dicen document. generan una funcion en un input de texto en la cual me salen el numero de caracteres que ingreso en el input como lo veran en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo demas del codigo que sigue abajo es una parte para que funcione un tipo de scroll horizontal en mi pagina, pero al colocar los 2 codigos no me sirve el contador de caracteres del primer codigo, sera que estoy colocando algo mal que crea algun conflicto?

Este es mi script.js asi mismo como esta acá solo necesito saber si hay algo mal en el codigo siguiente:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text2').value.length
})

var browser = function() {
    var x = {
        canUse: function(g) {},
        init: function() {}
    };
    return x.init(), x
}();
! function(x, g) {}(this, function() {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas agregando el listener `keyup` a todo el DOM.

```
let input = document.getElementById('text2');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = input.value.length;
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo ya me lo solucionaste!! crack!, aun ando aprendiendo